# Need an Excel Formula that will subtract the most recent of 5 values in a column from the oldest

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am a strength and conditioning coach and need some assistance with breaking down my athletes assessment results. I need help writing a formula that will subtract the oldest of 5 test results from the most recent. The sheet has almost 3000 rows with every athlete having 5 rows each (semester 1, 2, 3, 4, and summer), regardless of their actual participation in said testing. So the formula basically needs to go down the column and take the first available value out of the 5 cells and subtract it from the last available value out of the 5 cells. The sheet is set up as such:

[image: Screenshot]

Please help! I am sorry if this does not give enough info, I am new to the site.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of a small relevant section of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Does your xl version have minifs and maxifs?

Comment: Please share some sample data, will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, thought I had included it in the OP. I have edited the OP with a screenshot.

Comment: @JosephT,, in attached screen shot where you want to get the answer & also name column are quit confusing,,, Last,First,,,, Last,, First,,, ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a formula which works when you put it into any of those gray rows titled CHANGE

It is a doozie, it looks like this:

`=INDEX(Values, SMALL(INDEX((Values<>0)*ROW(Values), 0), ROWS(Values)) - ROW(StartValue) + 1,1)-
INDEX(Values, SMALL(INDEX((Values<>0)*ROW(Values), 0), COUNTIF(Values, "")+1) - ROW(StartValue)+1,1)`

Where

- `Values` is the range of values, in my example this is `H5:H9`
- `StartValue` is the first cell in the range of values, for me this is `H5`

**How it works**

- The statement `INDEX((Values<>0)*ROW(Values), 0)` returns an array which is `0` when the cell is blank, and the row number of the cell when it is not blank
- The `SMALL()` function sorts those in ascending order, then returns the value in the array corresponding to its second argument

So in the example spreadsheet below, `INDEX((Values<>0)*ROW(Values), 0)` returns

```
0
6
7
8
0
```

`SMALL()` sorts it to look like this:

```
0
0
6  <- Row of first nonzero value, second argument to SMALL(): =COUNTIF(Values, "")+1 = 3
7
8  <- Row of last nonzero value, second argument to SMALL(): ROWS(Values) = 5
```

- Now that we know the row, we use `INDEX()` to obtain the value. The line `- ROW(StartValue) + 1` translates the row returned by `SMALL()` into an index
- So we are left with the most recent nonzero value from the first call to `INDEX()` and we subtract form it the most distant nonzero value from the second call to `INDEX()`

**Screenshot**

[image: Compute CHANGE Row]

**Link to Spreadsheet**

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00703532745940371093) is a link to download this sample spreadsheet. I ordinarily use FormulaChop to explain these formulas, but it does not work with the ROW() function. (Full Disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop). So I included a version of the formula that does work, and you can see it broken out on the FormulaChop Tab.

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM! THANKS!

Comment: @JosephT Glad it worked for you! Please accept this response as the answer to your question.

Comment: tried to message you but I don't know how on this site. Please see above comment.

Answer (score 0):

With the dates in column A (A2:A3001), the names in column B and the values in columns C, put the name to look up in F2 and use this formula in G2.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, B:B, F2, A:A, AGGREGATE(14, 7, (A$2:A$3001)/(B$2:B$3001=F2), 1))-
 SUMIFS(C:C, B:B, F2, A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, (A$2:A$3001)/(B$2:B$3001=F2), 1))
```

Comment: This is returning all 0's for the value

Comment: That's the risk of asking a question without providing sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for?

[[image: Picture 1]]

In the picture, we have have two users. yellow data is what you have in your sheet (I think, with many users), and other columns are there to evaluate these using simple formulas.

[image: Formulas used are in the picture below]

Comment: The VLOOKUP columns are returning #REF!

Comment: After looking at your sheet, this might be the best way to address, a simple formula. I have added another solution down below

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a versatile method to solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put name of athlete in cell `D112`.
- Write nth value's position in Cell `C114` & `C115`.
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `D114`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$112:$A$128,SMALL(IF($B$112:$B$128=D$112,ROW($B$112:$B$128)-ROW(INDEX($B$112:B$128,1,1))+1),C114)),"")}`

- Write formula in `D117` to get the result.

## Edited:

*Since OP included sample data therefore I've decided to redraw the procedure to achieve the goal.*

[image]

- Array formula in Cell `Z1` & fill down:

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($W$3:$W$19,SMALL(IF($U$3:$U$19=X$1,ROW($U$3:$U$19)-ROW(INDEX($U$3:U$19,1,1))+1),Y1)),"")}`

---

- Formula in Cell `W8`:

`=IF($X$1=$U$3,Z$1-Z$2,"")`

**N.B.**

- It would formula of you choice, to subtract `1st` value from `5th`or vice versa.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this formula in Cell `W14` & in `W20`, also replace `$U$3` with `$U$9` and `$U$15` in successive formula in Cells `W14` & in `W20`.
- Keep changing athlete's name in Cell `D112` & `X1` to get new result.
- Later on for neatness you may hide range `Y1:Z2`.
- You may also create `Drop Down list` for names in Cell `X1`.

**Key feature:**

- This method allows the user to alter nth value's position any time (*in C114, C115 & Y1, Y2*) if & when the list of observations increase or even decrease for respected athletes.
- Which avoids edit the formula to get result from different combination.
- Also, you may replace Range `$A$112:$A$128` , `$B$112:$B$128` and `$W$3:$W$19` , `$U$3:$U$19` with *Dynamic Named Range*, which automatically adjusts data range in case user include or delete values in both *Name* & *Value* Column.

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:M$6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6=AN$2,ROW($B$2:$B$6)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:B$6,1,1))+1),AO2)),"")

I have edited this formula as such: 
The formula is in cell AP2
My values to be subtracted are in column M
Your second name column (C) is my column AN

I am getting a 0 in the first cell ao2 and blank when I copy it down.

[link](https://ibb.co/LCp0Y8m)

Comment: @JosephT,, put value in M2 is blank,,, since you have not written real names all are similar that's Y formula is unable to justify match,,, my suggestion is create data as I did & try the formula will work,,,!! I've added the Screen Shot,,.

Comment: @JosephT,, the attached Screen Shot is different than the question, since you have separate segment for every athlete  ??

Comment: @JosephT,, now check my post I've edited with something new according to the sample data, you have had included with the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for
[Picture showing how the results look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKbf9.png)

This is how the formula looks like, it is very simple to use
[Picture showing formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQPCk.png)

How to create formula?
Press Alt+F11 and copy paste the following

Public Function Diff2(n1 As Double, n2 As Double, n3 As Double, n4 As Double, n5 As Double)

index1 = 0
index2 = 0

'find first number
If n1 > 0 Then
FirstNum = n1
index1 = 1
ElseIf n2 > 0 Then
FirstNum = n2
index1 = 1
ElseIf n3 > 0 Then
FirstNum = n3
index1 = 3
ElseIf n4 > 0 Then
FirstNum = n4
index1 = 4
End If

'find Second number
If n5 > 0 Then
SecNum = n5
index2 = 5
ElseIf n4 > 0 Then
SecNum = n4
index2 = 4
ElseIf n3 > 0 Then
SecNum = n3
index2 = 3
ElseIf n2 > 0 Then
SecNum = n2
index2 = 2
End If

'Error checking
If (index1 = 0) Or (index2 = 0) Or (index1 - index2 = 0) Then
Diff2 = "ERROR"
Else
Diff2 = SecNum - FirstNum
End If

End Function

[Picture showing excel VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15pLp.png)